# How to build parameter grid with FeatureUnion?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, nlp, tf-idf

I am trying to run this combined model, of text and numeric features, and I am getting the error `ValueError: Invalid parameter tfidf for estimator`. Is the problem in the `parameters` synthax?
Possibly helpful links:
[FeatureUnion usage](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-combine-textual-and-numerical-features-for-machine-learning-in-python-dc1526ca94d9)
[FeatureUnion documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.FeatureUnion.html)

```
tknzr = tokenize.word_tokenize
vect = CountVectorizer(tokenizer=tknzr, stop_words={'english'}, max_df=0.9, min_df=2)
scl = StandardScaler(with_mean=False)
tfidf = TfidfTransformer(norm=None)
parameters = {
    'vect__ngram_range': [(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 2), (2, 3), (3, 3)],
    'tfidf__use_idf': (True, False),
    'clf__alpha': tuple(10 ** (np.arange(-4, 4, dtype='float'))),
    'clf__loss': ('hinge', 'squared_hinge', 'log', 'modified_huber', 'perceptron'),
    'clf__penalty': ('l1', 'l2'),
    'clf__tol': (1e07, 1e-6, 1e-5, 1e-4, 1e-3)
}

combined_clf = Pipeline([
    ('features', FeatureUnion([
        ('numeric_features', Pipeline([
            ('selector', transfomer_numeric)
        ])),
        ('text_features', Pipeline([
            ('selector', transformer_text),
            ('vect', vect),
            ('tfidf', tfidf),
            ('scaler', scl),
        ]))
    ])),
    ('clf', SGDClassifier(random_state=42,
                          max_iter=int(10 ** 6 / len(X_train)), shuffle=True))
])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/compose.html#nested-parameters), nested parameters must be accessed by the `__` (double underscore) syntax. Depending on the depth of the parameter you want to access, this applies recursively. The parameter `use_idf` is under:

`features` > `text_features` > `tfidf` > `use_idf`

So the resulting parameter in your grid needs to be:

```py
'features__text_features__tfidf__use_idf': [True, False]
```

Similarly, the syntax for `ngram_range` should be:

```py
'features__text_features__vect__ngram_range': [(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 2), (2, 3), (3, 3)]
```